# Rounding to one decimal place?

Tags: java, double, rounding

I have the following variables initialized to the user inputs,

int completedPasses = reader1.nextInt();

int attemptedPasses = reader2.nextInt();

double completionRatio = (250 / 3) * ((completedPasses / attemptedPasses) - 0.3);

How do I round the computation above to a double of one decimal place?

Comment: you can use Math.round

Comment: @hhafeez No you can't. See the duplicate.

Comment: You can't. Doubles don't have decimal places. They have binary places. If you want decimal places you must use a decimal radix. See `DecimalFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Use DecimalFormat:

```
     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
     df.format(completionRatio);
```

Or Math.round:

```
    Math.round(completionRatio);
```